# Python searching for partial matches in a list

Tags: python, list, set, match

I am having an issue figuring out the logic of solving this problem. I have a list that would look like this format:

```
['blah', 'foo', 'bar', 'jay/day']
```

anything without a '/' is a normal name. Anything with a '/' character is a name + an additional string. What I want to do is iterate over a set of tuples and check if the first element of the tuple matches any name in the list. However, I also want the name "jay" to match with "jay/day", but I do not want partial matches (i.e. do not want "ja" to partial match to "jay").

Basically I want a full match of any of the names while ignoring anything after a "/" in a single entry.

Any help with figuring out the logic of this will be appreciated.

Comment: Show expected value + what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

Go for a traditional loop way. This matches names in tuple with names in lst:

```
lst = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar', 'jay/day']
tupl = ('unknown', 'bar', 'foo', 'jay', 'anonymous', 'ja', 'day')

for x in tupl:
    for y in lst:
        if x == y.split('/')[0]:
            print(x, y)

# bar bar
# foo foo                                                     
# jay jay/day
```

Comment: This will fail the case if 'day' is in `tupl`.

Comment: I figured a loop would be the way to go, just did not want to add in an additional loop to my already big nested loop. But if it's the only practical way I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Endyd, Thanks. Just addressed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the list every time and splitting by '/', you can just copy the list to a new list with only what's before the '/'

```
input_tuples = [('jay', 'other'), ('blah', 'other stuff')]
list_strings = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar', 'jay/day']

# Using a set as @Patrick Haugh suggested for faster look up
new_strings = {x.split('/')[0] for x in list_strings}

for tup in input_tuples:
    if tup[0] in new_strings:
        print('found', tup[0]) 
# outputs found jay, found blah
```

Comment: I think this is the right approach, but you can make `new_strings` a set instead of a list for faster lookups.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity purposes, I will create a new list while will ignore `/` and characters following `/` then do the check. Using `set` to find intersection

```
import re
test_list = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar', 'jay/day']
set(('unknown', 'bar', 'foo', 'jay', 'anonymous', 'ja')).intersection(set([re.sub("/[\w]*","",i) for i in test_list]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
import re
l = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar', 'jay/day']

def match(name, l):
    for each in l:
        if re.match("^{}(\/|$)".format(name), each):
            return True # each if you want the string
    return False
```

Results:

```
match('ja', l) # False

match('jay', l) # True

match('foo', l) # True
```

Use a tuple:

```
tupl = ('unknown', 'bar', 'foo', 'jay', 'anonymous', 'ja')

res = [match(x, l) for x in tupl]
```

res:

```
[False, True, True, True, False, False]
```